# Подсчёт количества символов при заполнении формы

Tags: php, css, javascript

Всем привет. На сайте есть поле textarea, которое нужно ограничить по количеству символов, вводимых в неё. Как можно реализовать, чтобы при заполнении формы отображалось, сколько символов ещё можно напечатать. А при достижении нуля символов ввод символов становился невозможным.

Comment: а гугл ах..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/count-characters-in-textarea

Comment: А на русском такая информация есть? Это что, американская сеть знаний?

Comment: Who knows...

Comment: Не знаете по поводу инфы на русском? Или по поводу сети знаний?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ограничения длины, можно использовать атрибут `maxlength`, например:

```
<textarea maxlength="xxx"></textarea>
```

Но, разумеется, стоит ещё делать проверку на стороне сервера.

Чтобы вывести оставшуюся длину и обрезать строку, при потребности:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    var maxl=$(this).attr('maxlength'),
        l=maxl-$(this).val().length;
    $('#xxx').html(l);
    if(l<0)
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,maxl));
})
```

В примере `xxx` — `id` элемента, где отображается длина.

Comment: Простите, опять поспешил и не перепроверил `:)`

Так как не все браузеры ограничивают текстовые поля по `maxlength`, нужно дополнительно делать это с помощью `javascript`. Ответ обновил.

Comment: Вы точно вешаете обработчик после загрузки `DOM`-дерева?

Поместите код в событие `$(document).ready(function(){...})` или `$(function(){...})`.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sv9HU/).

Comment: Я конечно полный... Теперь всё работает. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Ничего понять не могу. Всё равно не работает почему-то

Comment: Всё. jquery добавил. Заработало.